# Undefined values in chart.js from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, chart.js

i am working on showing data in a bar chart with `chart.js` . my json response is already ready there but chart says its undefined values.

**here is jquery with json**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php base_url();?>/charts/getsome",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var month = [];
            var customers = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                month.push("Customer in" + data[i].apply_month);
                customers.push(data[i].no_customers);
            }
            var chartdata = {
                labels: month,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'monthly customers',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: customers
                    }
                ]
            };

            // alert(chartdata);

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**below is a snap for json response in console**

[image]

**And here is also a snap for chart with error**

[image]

Please guide me where i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: what data you have in customers?  can you show us?

Comment: @Dinesh why did you remove your answer? You seemed to be correct :) see [without parsing the string](http://jsfiddle.net/18y58dc9/1/) and [with parsing the string](http://jsfiddle.net/18y58dc9/2/)

Comment: thanks @Dinesh. i just want to show apply_month with constomer and no_customers as their value

Comment: Mr. @George. have you any suggestion about this?

Comment: @George thanks . because of you undeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting response as a string. you should parse using `JSON.parse(data)`

```
success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data)
            //the rest of your code
         }
```

Comment: can you guide me, where i can place this parse code? please

Comment: @AshishVyas underneath/replace the `console.log(data)`.